# Cannot extend base.html from parent directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I have this directory structure:

```
root:
+pages
 -base.html
 ...
 +en
  -index.html
  ...
index.py
...
```

When I render index.html from index.py, it says it cannot find base.html.

This is the tag I used in index.html to extend base.html:

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}
```

This is the code in index.py:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'pages/it/index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Which would be the correct way? I'm using Google web app and Django templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use paths like that in the extends tag. But you don't need to - assuming your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is `root/pages`, you just do `extends "base.html"`.

Comment: thank you. i googled for template_dirs, some problems there: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2661

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question very much like this here: [TemplateDoesNotExist on python app-engine django 1.2 while template rendering relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263623/templatedoesnotexist-on-python-app-engine-django-1-2-while-template-rendering-rel)

The technique demonstrated there will allow you to have full control over the directory structure in which you store your templates.