# GAE templates doesn't work

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates

I have the following code in my settins.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'html').replace("\\","/"),
)
```

and in the request handler:

```
r = template.render('mt.html', {'some_content':blabla,})
```

I'm expecting, that the template will be loaded from the /project_dir/html/mt.html file.
But it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
handler.get(*groups)
File "D:\ap\pz4\pz4\main.py", line 33, in get
x8= template.render(fn, {'some_content':blabla,})
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.py", line 91, in render
t = _load_user_django(template_path, debug)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.py", line 113, in _load_user_django
template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_3\django\template\loader.py", line 157, in get_template
template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_3\django\template\loader.py", line 138, in find_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: mt.html
```

In the same time, it works fine, when I call it using direct folder definition:

```
r = template.render(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'html/mt.html').replace("\\","/"),{'some_content':blabla,})
```

GAE is 1.6.3 (local), the django version (using use_library('django', 'xxx')) checked with 0.96, 1.2 and 1.3, result is the same.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem in the webapp engine: the "**_load_user_django**" method (from C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp on my system) **overrides** user-defined TEMPLATE_DIRS variable:

```
def _load_user_django(path, debug):
  """Load the given template using the django found in third_party."""
  abspath = os.path.abspath(path)

  if not debug:
    template = template_cache.get(abspath, None)
  else:
    template = None

  if not template:
    directory, file_name = os.path.split(abspath)
    new_settings = {
        'TEMPLATE_DIRS': (directory,),
        'TEMPLATE_DEBUG': debug,
        'DEBUG': debug,
        }

    old_settings = _swap_settings(new_settings)
    ...
```

as a result, when the **get_template_sources** method (from the filesystem.py) try to call "safe_join(template_dir, template_name)" it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 317, in post
    exec(compiled_code, globals())
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_3\django\utils\_os.py", line 46, in safe_join
    'path component (%s)' % (final_path, base_path))
ValueError: The joined path (x:\app_path\html\mt.html) is located outside of the base path component (x:\app_path\html\sub_templ_folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

by default django looks for templates in app_name/templates/app_name/template.html (yeah, app_name repeated)

so it looks like in your case, it'll look for a template in project_dir/html/project_dir/template.html, assuming that project_dir is the same as your django app name.

Comment: I put the "mt.html" into the following folders:

app_root
app_root/html
app_root/html/app_name

but it still not working.

Comment: The docs might help you a bit more than myself.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/

It looks like I'm on the wrong track, I was using subfolders in my templates, but you're not doing that.  It should be pretty easy to debug by adding a line to print out either the template_path or file_name in the appropriate places specified in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In stock GAE, Django's `TEMPLATE_DIRS` facility isn't used. I do the following, which is basically straight out of [the templates docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html):

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Where, in this case, 'index.html' is a resource living at the root of the app. If your templates are in a directory within the app, adjust the `os.path.join()` accordingly.

Comment: That's clear, it is also works for me, but I need to use "extends template" feature, and it work only when all of the templates are stored in the same (root) folder.
But I have deep (2-3 levels) folder structure and don't like to store ~40 templates to the same folder.

Comment: @user1276220: My answer on a related question has a technique for allowing you to use relative paths in your `extends` and `include` calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263623/templatedoesnotexist-on-python-app-engine-django-1-2-while-template-rendering-re

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have the following line in your yaml file

```
- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates
```

If you remove those two lines your code will work just fine assuming that your path is the following:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/home.html')
```